# Recent files by project rather than recent files and recent projects separately

Tags: projectile, recentf

**Note**: This question is really about Projectile and Recentf. I'm using them in the context of Spacemacs, so I describe that context, but the question isn't really intended to be Spacemacs-specific.

The Spacemacs home buffer, which can be configured via `dotspacemacs-startup-lists`, show by default a number of recent files and projects. They are, however, displayed in two separate lists, so if I've been working with a lot of files in one project, then all the recent files are from one project, even if I set `recents` to a large amount like 24, all the recent files will be from one project. What I'd really like is to see the recent files *by project*. Suppose for example I had a `vegetables` project and a `fruit` project. I would want to see something like:

> vegetables
>
> - vegetables/lettuce.el
> - vegetables/squash.el
> - vegetables/tomatoes.el
>
> fruit
>
> - fruit/apple.py
> - fruit/orange.py
> - fruit/banana.py

How can I achieve this with Recentf/Projectile? Is this a matter of configuration, or of needing to just code up the logic myself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seeing that no one offered an answer here, I dug more into the code that Spacemacs is using for this, and it appeared that there was no pre-existing solution; since the code is rather Spacemacs-specific, I doubt there is some existing package out there that does it.

As such, I implemented it and submitted a [PR](https://github.com/syl20bnr/spacemacs/pull/14259) to Spacemacs, which has been merged. The feature is available in Spacemacs now, and anyone educated in Emacs Lisp could port it to their own configs if necessary.